# gcc doesn't find header file in static library I made

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I made a static library.
This not have error, library file too.
So, I tried use that library.

```
gcc -o hash_gen main.c -L../  -lhashbundle
```

Library file exist in that directory `../`, library file name is `libhashbundle.a`.
So, I thought not have problem in this command.
but I tried compile with gcc, but gcc print this error.

```
main.c:4:10: fatal error: 'hash.h' file not found
#include "hash.h"
          ^
```

I don't understand. I made library `make`, and this is `Makefile`

```
all : libhashbundle.a

libhashbundle.a : hash.o
        ar rscv libhashbundle.a hash.o

hash.o : src/hash.c
        gcc -c src/hash.c

clean:
        rm -rf hash.o
```

I thought this code many times, but I didn't found error.

and this is directory tree

```
tree

Makefile
libhashbundle.a

|src
  |hash.c
  |hash.h

|test
  |main.c
```

So, I ask to you.
How could solve this problem?

Comment: You need to put the header file somewhere where the compiler can search for it...

Answer (score 1):

You only specified a library search path (`-L`).

If you want a header search path, you need to use `-I`.

```
gcc -o hash_gen main.c -I.. -L.. -lhashbundle
```

Comment: I'm not want a header search. I want why not found header file in library. this library look like, static library, So, I include header `#include "hash.h"`.

Comment: You need a header search path, because `main.c` does not know where to find `hash.h` (it's not in the same directory as `main.c`, or any of the default search paths).  Now that you've edited your question to show the directory structure, you should modify that line using `-I../src`.  Or you can `#include "../src/hash.h".  Up to you...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the fact that you're running your build from your "root" directory, not from **/src/**. So when the compiler sees `#include "hash.h"` it will try to open the file in the current directory, which will be `/` rather than `/src/` (where the files are).

To fix this, just add your source directory to the include search paths using `-Isrc`:

gcc -o hash_gen main.c -Isrc -lhashbundle

Note that I omitted `-L` since the library file is in your current working directory and should be found there anyway.